# gcc не находит stdio

Tags: linux, gcc

Работаю в PSLinuxOS. При компиляции gcc проекта на С,

```
include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   ...
   return 0
};
```

пишет что не может найти stdio.h. 
Но он на самом деле он есть и лежит в  /usr/include. Установлен из пакета glibs-devel-2.31-5pclos2020 package. Заметил что в PATH нет пути к библиотекам, может поэтому не могу найти?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. В коде написал:

```
include <stdio>
```

забыл .h указать... поэтому и не находил

Comment: Отметьте тогда свой ответ как принятый, пожалуйста, чтобы вопрос не попадал в неотвеченные